# Vaadin upgrade from 14 to 23, where to put @CssImport

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I used the Vaadin 14 business starter app which appears to have been discontinued in Vaadin 23. This app put custom CSS under the MainLayout:

```
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/charts.css", themeFor = "vaadin-chart", include = "vaadin-chart-default-theme")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/floating-action-button.css", themeFor = "vaadin-button")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/components/grid.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/border-radius.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/icon-size.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/margin.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/padding.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/shadow.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/spacing.css")
@CssImport("./styles/lumo/typography.css")
@CssImport("./styles/misc/box-shadow-borders.css")
@CssImport(value = "./styles/styles.css", include = "lumo-badge")
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge")
```

Does this stay here or does it move to AppConfig along with the @PWA and other annotations.
I ask because the CSS styling is broken on the menu and doesn't seem to change wither it is on MainLayout or AppConfig.

Any ideas? Is this a styling incompatibility between 14 and 23, or have the requirements on where to place the @CssImport changed?

Has anyone else successfully ported the discontinued business starter app from 14 to 23?

Some help from the Vaadin folk would be appreciated as this business starter app was a explicitly marketed benefit to getting a Pro subscription and now appears to have been dropped.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it.

Comment: Can you show what is broken?

Comment: I've just rolled back to 14 so I cannot create a screenshot anymore, but the size, spacing and alignment of the menu items and icons was wrong. There was also no spacing between the icon and the menu item text.

Comment: Those issues are almost certainly caused by changes to Vaadin components between 14 and 23, since the correct placement of @CssImport annotations has not changed. I'd suggest posting separate questions about the specific issues you're having, or asking about them on Vaadin's Discord chat at vaad.in/chat. If the issues are only in the menu then it will probably not require much modification to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

The currently recommended way is to use the [custom theme folder](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme) (for example, `frontend/themes/mytheme`), and place your style sheets there. Then use the `@Theme("mytheme")` annotation to choose that theme.

The `./styles/styles.css` file should likely be the main theme style sheet (`frontend/themes/mytheme/styles.css`). All other @CssImports without a `themeFor` attribute can be on the same folder, and imported in the main style sheet with the standard CSS `@import`.

But, since Vaadin 23 now has the [Lumo utility classes](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/foundation/utility-classes) built-in, you might not need those additional style sheets (for example, `margin.css`). Though, the CSS class names they define might not be 1:1 with the newer utility classes.

Any @CssImports with the `themeFor` attribute should be placed in the “special” `components` folder, where each file name corresponds to a component tag name (for example, `frontend/themes/my-theme/components/vaadin-chart.css`).

Comment: Hi Jouni. Thanks for this but I really don't want to go through the effort of re-aligning, moving and fixing all of the CSS that was from the vaadin business app example. I was hoping that the Vaadin team would continue to support the business app starter or at an absolute minimum, at least give us the porting instructions necessary to port this app from 14 to 23, instead of every customer using it having to redo this common work themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There's a migration manual for `@CssImport` at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/upgrading/recommended-changes in chapter "Refactor Styles to a Custom Theme Folder".

But there are two things to consider (despite it is named "Recommended Changes")...:

1. The "Style Loading Order" may be different than before, have a look at the list in https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme/#style-loading-order
2. Migrating your CSS to Vaadin 23 is not just exchanging an annotation. You have to do a lot more, have a look at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/upgrading/essential-steps/#update-your-css
3. Wrongly sized icons: have a look here: [Vaadin migration 14 to 23: icons have different size (viewbox wrong?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914732/vaadin-migration-14-to-23-icons-have-different-size-viewbox-wrong)

Comment: Thanks for this, but to me it sounds like a really good reason not to upgrade to 23, we have enough other work to do than chase around CSS fixes on Vaadin Pro code. I will wait and hope that the business app gets 23 support.